# Joining derived tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

**EDIT: I am using phpMyAdmin interface, and I have been copy/paste the codes from phpMyAdmin to here. The phpMyAdmin seems to run a "different code" as I run the following code, and generating some error message that are referring to that "different code", causing huge confusion.**

** Final edit: It seems Safari is causing this: it run the "different query" when I try to run 2nd query below. Use Firefox instead, and it generate correct results. Thanks for the help and sorry for the confusion. **

I have two tables: newsFeeds, comments, where

** newsFeeds contains column PID, comments contains column FID.**

I want to join rows in two tables with matching PID = FID. My code is:

```
SELECT * FROM newsFeeds
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM
    comments
)
ON comments.FID = newsFeeds.PID
```

and the error message is "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias".

I then add in `AS newtb` after `)` according to other posts here. And the code is then:

```
SELECT * FROM newsFeeds
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM
    comments
) AS newtb
ON newtb.FID = newsFeeds.PID
```

But another error shows up: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN( SELECTFID,COUNT(*) AScount FROMcomments 
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 8`

I wonder how to correctly do this?

Comment: When you add the alias what is the error?

Comment: Question should be on dba.se

Comment: @bluefeet: The error message is: " #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN( SELECTFID,COUNT(*) AScount FROMcomments 
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 6 "

Comment: @Lelouch Can you edit your question and post your query that you are running that is generating the error?  The more details the better.

Comment: Actually I recall that the command worked ONCE, and afterwards fails.

Comment: @Almo no this doesn't belong on DBA.se

Comment: You need a table alias -- `INNER JOIN(SELECT * FROM tb_2) AS foo ON tb_1.FID = foo.FID`

Comment: Why not? SO is littered with questions about sql that have comments about this stuff needing to be on dba. This is a genuine question, BTW.

Comment: @Almo sorry, dba.SE is not designed for trivial query syntax problems.

Comment: But should those be on SO, either?

Comment: @Almo I think you should read the FAQs for DBA.SE (http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before you start voting to migrate questions there.

Comment: @Almo Probably not. Just because it's an off-topic question because of its nature, does not mean you should just shovel it to some other site so they can deal with it instead. This is the kind of behavior that kills our ability to migrate questions freely between sites in the first place - notice that you can't choose to migrate to all sites, only those that have a relatively good record of often-migrated questions. If you start sending crap to other sites, they'll request to get removed from the list. Reserve migration for *good* questions you *know* belong on the other site. Please.

Comment: I just thought SQL stuff belonged over there. Reading FAQ now. :)

Comment: Can you show the actual code you're using? It's tough to try and understand how the code in the question leads to that error message, when it's completely different.

Comment: @Lelouch Is that your actual query you are using?  The content of the error message doesn't match what you posted.  Plus your error message has sql without any spaces in the text which could cause some problems.

Comment: @bluefeet: the same sql, just edited the table name (from original "newsFeeds" to "tb_1", and "comments" to "tb_2" for better look).

Comment: Why on earth are you using a subquery in the first place? Why not just `SELECT * FROM newsFeeds INNER JOIN comments ON newsFeeds.PID = comments.FID`?

Comment: @Lelouch It can't be the same because the error is showing a `COUNT(*)` but your posted query doesn't show any of that.  It is difficult to help if you don't provide all of the correct details.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: post edited, with actual table name I am using; and the reason is I want to first deal with simplest model; my final goal is to not `SELECT *` from both tables, but only first selecting a few rows from each tables, and then do the matching+joining.

Comment: @bluefeet: I have been copy/paste the message, after I run the code (in the phpmyadmin interface). Is the browser "caching" some of my old command?

Comment: Don't dumb things down for anyone. You're not dealing with the simplest model first if the error message you're getting has to do with a much more complex query than the one you're saying doesn't work. If you want specific help for your query, post the specific query that's causing the problem. Mixing and matching is confusing, frustrating, and downright unfair to people who are giving their own free time to help you solve *your* problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I totally agree with you, and I thank all of you helping me! But as I run the SAME code in phpmyadmin interface, it generate the error message, and I copy it. I run it 10 times as I typed this response, and that's what I got.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your phpmyadmin interface, if you send it one query and it is giving you an error message about a different query. Don't know how to help you with that, sorry - doesn't seem like `SELECT * FROM comments` would even work if you can't get phpmyadmin to send the right query.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Ok. Thank you all for the help. Simple queries work and those in the post do not. I'll find some other ways.

Comment: @Lelouch Something is really wrong if simple queries work fine, but when you use the one on your post, then it "decides" to run another one. This isn't right, you are probably overlooking an issue, or you haven't posted the right code

Comment: @Lamak: I copy/paste my code between here and phpMyAdmin, and I am using Safari (latest version). I will try a new browser.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Should I turn off this post? It's not solving anything.

Comment: I think you need to contact phpmyadmin support, or use another tool. The problem you're describing now is not a programming problem in any shape or form, and is different than the actual syntax problems you describe in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should correct this by removing the derived table:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_1 INNER JOIN
     tb_2
     ON tb_2.FID = tb_1.PID;
```

MySQL has a tendency to materialize derived tables, which hurts performance.

The answer to your question, though, is to add a name after the parentheses:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_1 INNER JOIN
     (SELECT *
      FROM tb_2
     ) t2
     ON t2.FID = tb_1.PID;
```

Comment: Actually I also tried this, from answers in other posts. But same error #1064.

Comment: @Lelouch . . . Your other error is because you are missing spaces between lines.  `SELECTFID` should be `SELECT FID` and `FROMcomments` should be `FROM comments`.

Comment: I think something is wrong with the phpMyAdmin interface. Other is pointing out the error message doesn't match my query. But thanks.

Comment: @Lelouch . . .  One possibility is that you are concatenating strings together and they don't have spaces at the end/beginning of each substring.

Comment: Use Firefox in the end, and everything works. Question on keyword `AS`: it seems your second query works the same with or without `AS`: `(...) AS t2` and `(...) t2` gives the same results.

Comment: I prefer to only have the `as` for column aliases and not for table aliases.  This happens to be what Oracle enforces and is supported by all other databases, except MS Access. There the `as` is required for table aliases.